# What are the chances of at least $4$ heads if you flip a coin $5$ times

Tags: probability

How would I go about solving this problem?

> What are the chances of *at least* $4$ heads if you flip a coin $5$ times

I constructed a tree diagram but I don't think that is correct. The answer I got was $\frac{1}{8}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the $2^5=32$ possible sequences of heads and tails is equally likely. There's one sequence with all heads, and there are $5$ different sequences with four heads, corresponding to the $5$ possible positions of the one tails result. Thus the probability is $(1+5)/32=6/32=3/16$.

Answer (score 0):

Apply Bernoulli's Formula:

$$\frac{1}{2^5}\left(\binom{5}{4}+\binom{5}{5}\right)$$